# Install prerelease gem of sass 3.3 failed (sass requires listen (~> 0.7))

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass

I'm trying to install the prerelease version of sass (3.3) because of the added sourcemap support but it fails with the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
    Unable to resolve dependencies: sass requires listen (~> 0.7)
```

I used the following command:

```
gem install sass --pre
```

Until now i had sass v3.2.8 installed. Uninstalling this one prior installing the pre-version did not help.

Any ideas?

One more thing: I also thought about installing it directly from the git-repository but i don't know from which branch i can get the pre-version?

I've posted this question also on the issue tracker of the sass-git-repository: https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/811

---

Edit:
I just tried to install the master-branch from git-hub with "rake install", but this gives me the following error:

```
WARNING: vendor/listen doesn't exist, and this isn't a git repository so I can't get it automatically!
chmod -R a+rx bin
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (127): [chmod -R a+rx bin...]
C:/Users/xxx/sass-master/Rakefile:44:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => install => package => permissions
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No surprise that the pre-release has issues with it. That said, I managed to get it working using  `gem install sass --version=3.3.0.alpha.184`. If you want compass, try using v0.12.2.

Then you'd need to run SASS with compass, not SASS. Example:

```
sass --compass --sourcemap styles.scss:styles.css
```

Info from here: https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1108

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue (probably the same but manifested with slightly different syntax) in that I was getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing sass:
    sass requires listen (~> 0.7, runtime)
```

After trying the above answer by imjared which didn't work for me, I tried using `gem install sass --version=3.3.0.alpha.103` as seen in a screenshot of a Terminal in this http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/developing-with-sass-and-chrome-devtools/ article, note the `.103` and not `.184` on the end of the Terminal command here.